# DB2: Duplicate rows generically

Tags: sql, db2, duplicates, rows

Can you help me duplicating rows generically in DB2 please!? The task is to duplicate rows that match a certain criteria (like: WHERE version=abc) and reinserting them into the same table with updated value on some columns (like: version=abc+1).

With generically i mean, that i cannot explicitly list the attributes of the rows, it has to work for arbitrary tables.

//EDIT for clarification:

Let's say there is a table with the attributes ID, NAME, VERSION. Now i want to copy some rows of this table (WHERE version=4) into the same table but with version increased by 1. For this i need an SQL statement.

The same SQL statement should work on a table with the attributes ID, COUNTRY, VERSION.

So, there is always the (technical) ID and there is always the VERSION. About the identifier and number of the other attributes there is no information upfront.

Comment: Can we help you?  Yes, but only if you ask a specific, detailed, question (which you haven't).

Comment: Then tell me what information is missing to answer the question. I just need an SQL statement that does the explained task.

Comment: We can't give you a SQL Statement if we don't even know your table structure.  Your requirement is also very vague...

Comment: The table structure doesn't matter imho. Anyway, let's say there is a table with the attributes ID, NAME, VERSION. Now i want to copy some rows of this table (WHERE version=4) into the same table but with version increased by 1.

Comment: I doubt you could do it with a single statement, but it seems relatively straightforward when using a temporary table.

Comment: You can "duplicate" via a simple `INSERT INTO ... SELECT version + 1 FROM ...`.  The trick is going to be the application - you need dynamic SQL to change the columns.  You can't do it in one statement.  I think I'm a little worried about the fact that you want to do this at all.  Why do you want to just bump version like this?

Comment: Because the DB design was done like this (wasn't my decision) ;) I've implemented it the way that the application does it by itselve now. I also think i wouldn't be possible with a (simple) statement without cursors etc... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

> let's say there is a table with the attributes ID, NAME, VERSION. Now i want to copy some rows of this table (WHERE version=4) into the same table but with version increased by 1.

Based on your comments above, this might work for you:

```
Insert  Into Table
        (Name, Version)
Select  Name, Version + 1
From    Table
Where   Version = 4
```

Comment: I need a generic solution for this. It should also work for tables with ID, NAME, STREET, VERSION. The only thing that's always included is VERSION.

Comment: I am not understanding what you mean by a generic version...  Can you please explain what you're trying to accomplish?